# fitting a plane into a cloud of points (3d)

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, slice, curve-fitting

I have a data file containing multiple columns of data,I would like to extract 3 columns (that indicate the coordinates ) out of this data file and put them in another file, then using the newly created file I would like to fit a plane or surface (or whatever you would like to call it) using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit



### processing function    
def store(var,textfile):
    data=loadtxt(textfile,skiprows=1)
    p0=[]
    p1=[]
    p2=[]
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        p0.append(float(data[i,2]))
        p1.append(float(data[i,3]))
        p2.append(float(data[i,4]))
    var.append(p0)
    var.append(p1)
    var.append(p2)

#extracting the data from a textfile
datafile1='cracks_0101005_5k_tensionTestCentreCrack_l0.001a0_r0.01.txt'
a1=[]
store(a1, datafile1)


rcParams.update({'legend.numpoints':1,'font.size': 20,'axes.labelsize':25,'xtick.major.pad':10,'ytick.major.pad':10,'legend.fontsize':14})
lw=2
ms=10

#fitting a surface(curve) into the data

def func(data, m, n, o): 
    return m*data[:,0] + n*data[:,2] + o 

guess=(1,1,1)

params, pcov = curve_fit(func, a1[::2, :2], a1[:,1], guess)
print (params)
```

And I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fitcurve.py", line 41, in <module>
    params, pcov = curve_fit(func, a1[::2, :2], a1[:,1], guess)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Would you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Just to make it more clear :
I am trying to have Y as my dependent function, so it would be a function of X and Z.
Apparently `a1[]` is a list and not an array right?
But even when I change it to an array `Myarray=np.asarray(a1)` I get some other weird messages.
I would appreciate if someone could help me understand the issue here.

Cheers

Comment: What does the data actually represent? If you only use `data[:,0]` and `data[:,2]` I don't see the point of a three parameter fit.

Comment: ...also try the `unpack=True` possibility of loadtxt to avoid the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here possible errors I noticed in your code:

you want to fit `y` as function of `x,z` so the `X` array you want to sent is probably `a1[:, ::2]`. But that means that `func` already gets a `m,2` array so here it must be `return m*data[:,0] + n*data[:,1] + o`
Still I think it should be a two parameter fit not three. You can calculate a possible `m, n, o` from the according result.

```py
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
from random import random
style.use('ggplot')

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

""" make some data and save to file """
data = []
a, b, s = 1.233, -2.17, 5.2
for i in range(88):
    x = 10 * (2 * random() - 1)
    y = 10 * (2 * random() - 1)
    z = a * x +  b * y+ s * (2 * random() - 1) * 0.5
    data += [[x, y, z]]
data = np.array(data)
np.savetxt("data.txt", data)

""" get the data and use unpack to directly write into x,y,z variables"""
xData, yData, zData = np.loadtxt("data.txt", unpack=True)
"""...while I actally need the packed version as well, so I could load again"""
#allData = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
"""...or..."""
allData = np.array( zip(xData, yData, zData) )

def func(data, m, o): 
    return m * data[:,0] + o * data[:, 1] 
    
guess = (1, 1)
params, pcov = curve_fit(func, allData[:, ::2], allData[:,1], guess)

""" showing data and fit result"""
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = -params[0] / params[1] * X + 1 / params[1] * Y

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig1.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xData, yData, zData)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color='#4060a6', alpha=0.6 )
ax.set_title(
    "({:1.2f},{:1.2f})".format(
        -params[0] / params[1], 1 / params[1]
    )
)
plt.show()
```

[image: test result]

Note that while you fitted `y = m * x + o * z` I plot a wireframe of `z = a * x + b * y` mit `b = 1 / o` und `a = -m / o`, i.e. `n = 1`. You can rescale your `m, n, o` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of linear multiple regression of a flat surface:

```
import numpy as np

# the below "columns" of data could be i.e., x, y**2, sin(x), log(y), etc.
# numpy's array transpose can also  be handy in formatting the data in this way

# first "column" will regress to an offset parameter (a * 1.0, or just a)
# second "column" will regress the X data (b * X)
# third "column" will regress the Y data  (c * Y)
indepData = np.array([
[1.0, 11.0, 0.1], # first data point
[1.0 ,22.0, 0.2], # second data point
[1.0, 33.0, 0.3], # third data point
[1.0, 35.0, 0.5] # fourth data point
])

# Z data
depData = np.array([5.0, 60.0, 70.0, 185.0])


coeffs = np.linalg.lstsq(indepData, depData)[0]

print(coeffs)

X = 25.0
Y = 0.2
a = coeffs[0]
b = coeffs[1]
c = coeffs[2]

regressionPredictedValue = a + b*X + c*Y
print(regressionPredictedValue)
```